# Excel: AND function with structured references

Tags: excel, logical-operators, structured-references

When using Excel structured references, Assume this table (MyTable):

[image]

If I enter the following in a cell, I get 5 values:
`=MyTable[Col A]>2`

[image]

...and if I enter the following in another cell, I get 5 values:
`=MyTable[Col B]<9`

[image]

However, If I want to test both conditions in a logical AND and enter the following in a cell:
`=AND(MyTable[Col A]>2, MyTable[Col B]<9)`

...I get only one result (FALSE) becuase the AND function assesses all 10 logical expressions and returns a single value.

How do I get Excel to return 5 values, one for each row?

I've thought about using BYROW with a LAMBDA, but can't figure out how to write a suitable LAMBDA.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following formula-

```
=(MyTable[Col A]>2)*(MyTable[Col B]<9)
```

If you want to use `LAMBDA()` formula then go with `MAP()`.

```
=MAP(MyTable[Col A],MyTable[Col B],LAMBDA(x,y,AND(x>2,y<9)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. It was the MAP function that did the trick. The answer is much appreciated.

Comment: @MikeB Glad to know. If it helps then please consider to accept the answer (tick mark it).